# How can I change the picture that draws on the screen

Tags: android, android-image

This might seem like a silly qustion but how do you change the picture that draws on the screen.I have already been able to program a app were it draws a little icon where you touch the screen.So natually after I completed that I want to make it better by adding a option menu and the ability to change what icon you were being drown but when I ran the code the icon picture stayed the same.When I looked at it I found that when you click on any of the menu item it does do it's job and change the image id but when you go back to the main screen and try to create a new image it revertes back to the old image.I have no idea why it doesn't change because when I look at it everything make sense for it to change icon properly.If any one has any idea on what i am doing wrong or any suggestion on how to do this it would be greatly appreciate

Main

```
  public class main extends Activity {  

 /** Called when the activity is first created. */  



  MenuItem item2;  

  int item3=R.drawable.ic_launcher;  



 @Override  

 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  

     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  

    FrameLayout sv = new FrameLayout(this);  

     LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);  

     Panel test = new Panel(this);  

     //ImageButton button = new ImageButton(this);  



     ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);  

     sv.addView(test);  

     //ll.addView(button);  

     sv.addView(ll);  



     setContentView(sv);  



 }  



 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {  

     // TODO Auto-generated method stub  

     MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();  

     inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);  

     return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);  

 }  



 @Override  

 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {  

     // TODO Auto-generated method stub  



     Log.v("test", "item3 before is: "+item3);  



       item3=R.drawable.box;  



       Log.v("test", "item3 after is: "+item3);  





     return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);  

     }  
  }
```

Panel

```
 public class Panel extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {  

 private Bitmap image;  

 private ViewThread mThread;  

 private int x;  

 private int y;  

 private ArrayList<Element> mElements = new ArrayList<Element>();  



 public Panel(Context context) {  

     super(context );  

     image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),yantz.imageapp4.R.drawable.test);  

     getHolder().addCallback(this);  

     mThread = new ViewThread(this);  



 }  



 public void doDraw(Canvas canvas) {  

     canvas.drawColor(Color.CYAN);  
     canvas.drawBitmap(image, x, y, null);  

     synchronized (mElements){  

     for(Element element : mElements){  

         element.doDraw(canvas);  

     }  

     }  





 }  









 @Override  

 public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {  

     // TODO Auto-generated method stub  

     Log.v("test", "you have touched the sreen: ");  



     synchronized (mElements){  

     mElements.add(new Element(getResources(),(int) event.getX(),(int) event.getY()));  

 }  

 return super.onTouchEvent(event);  

 }  







 @Override  

 public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {  

     // TODO Auto-generated method stub  

 }  



 @Override  

 public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {  

     if (!mThread.isAlive()) {  

         mThread = new ViewThread(this);  

         mThread.setRunning(true);  

         mThread.start();  

     }  

 }  



 @Override  

 public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {  

     if (mThread.isAlive()) {  

         mThread.setRunning(false);  

     }  

 }  

 }
```

Elements

```
 public class Element extends main{  

 private int mX;  

 private int mY;  

 int location ;  

 private Bitmap mBitmap;  



 public Element(Resources res, int x, int y) {  



     Log.v("element", "item3 before location is: "+item3);  



     location =item3;  

     mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, location);  

     mX = x - mBitmap.getWidth() / 2;  

     mY = y - mBitmap.getHeight() / 2;  

     Log.v("element", "item3 before location is: "+item3);  



 }  







 public void doDraw(Canvas canvas) {  

     canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, mX, mY, null);  

 }  



 public void setlocation(int location2){  

     location=location2;  

 }  

}
```

ViewThread

```
    public class ViewThread extends Thread {  

     private Panel mPanel;  

     private SurfaceHolder mHolder;  

     private boolean mRun = false;  



     public ViewThread(Panel panel) {  

         mPanel = panel;  

         mHolder = mPanel.getHolder();  

     }  



     public void setRunning(boolean run) {  

         mRun = run;  

     }  



     @Override  

     public void run() {  

         Canvas canvas = null;  

         while (mRun) {  

             canvas = mHolder.lockCanvas();  

             if (canvas != null) {  

                 mPanel.doDraw(canvas);  

                 mHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);  

             }  

         }  

     }
```

}

Comment: can you please explain your problem clearly ? Question is not clear.

Comment: @YugandharBabu My qustion would be How can I change the picture I draw on to my surfaceview using a optionmenu

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    id="what ever you want";
//and set it to imagevIew;
}
```

if i have understood the uestion correctly,this happens because your activity pauses when it is not focused and resumes with default values.

Comment: I tryed your suggestion Vincent and I agree dyour Idea that the programing is resorting to a default value the problem is the Onreume() doesnt fix it I ran the code in the debuger and it only ran once at the very start.When It did thought it did thewhen  same thing as the OnOptionSelect where it changes the value of variable but when you try and draw a image on screen it reverted back to the class variable value not the one you just changed it to that happen both for the OnResume() and the OnOptionSelect().I show you a screenshot  of the debuggerbut I am not currently able to on stackoverflow